# How to expire views cache in code or with rule?

Tags: 7, views, caching

I have a view with block display that shows a user's picture and profile info. The view is cached for 1 hour.

How can I expire that cache when the user updates the profile?

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using [Views Cache Actions](http://drupal.org/project/cache_actions). It allows to use rules to expire a specific view or views displays when a certain event occurs (like user profile save).

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try [Views Content Cache](http://drupal.org/project/views_content_cache)

> This module implements a views cache plugin that is aware of content
>   and can provide caching for views, until the content in those views
>   changes.

Since, profile content is saved as a node the above module should work as it tell. Try and let us know !

OR

If above module doesn't address the isue we are looking for then use [hook_profile2_update](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.api.php/function/hook_profile2_update/7) to hook into profile update and use the logic in above module to clear cache of a respective views block.

Comment: I'm not using Profile2 module so my user profile aren't nodes. But good idea to take a look how it's done in that module.

Comment: I looked at the code but the way views builds the cache keys doesn't look trivial to me.